# Hiding Sourcecode on IIS Server (ASP.net)

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, iis, deployment

I have a question about hiding or encoding the source code on a server which runs IIS.

At the moment the source code is available and visible for all users who are logged into the server where the IIS Server is running.

Is there a way to hide the Code (encode) with Visual Studio or any other software?

I think the aspx (or *.html) web site code can not be encoded but (for example) the *.vb  code sites should be able to encode.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can simply `Publish` the website

Build Menu => Publish Web Site

So the code behind files `(*.aspx.cs)` will get converted to `dll(Bin/*.dll)` file.

Refer this: [Walkthrough: Publishing a Web Site](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1y1404zt%28v=vs.80%29.aspx)

Answer (score 2):

When you are ready to put your project live make sure that you.

1. Publish it.
2. When you publish it that you tell it to compile your code into a single library or code behind files.
3. If you want to protect your html as well then you should not select to make the site updateable.

These steps will protect your code but as for your web.config file you will need to look at some other articles on securing its info.

If you can, I would recommend ensuring that only the authorized people have access to the server and/or the code base running on the server.  If that is the case then you should be ok.

Answer (score 0):

Go to Build menu---> Click on Publish the Website.
then a folder get created on the base folder. and the encoded files are available there. That can be upload to the FTP account, then third party can't see the source code with the browser.